# 8086 not printing first character printing nulls instead

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, bios

There is an error in this code. The print_string doesnt print to the screen after pointing to the string, it only prints if the line in the code  `mov bx,8000h` is removed and the two lines after it, but then i cant write alot of bytes to ram the whole thing crashes after calling alloc and incrementing the basepointer like 20 times. what should i do, how do I get to write the string and make it not crash after writing like 20 bytes

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

SEAM_STD_BUFFER equ 0
SEAM_STD_LIMIT equ 255

xor ax,ax
mov bx,ax
mov bx,cx
mov dx,0
mov ds,bx
mov es,bx

mov bp,0
mov sp,bp
mov ss,bp
mov bx,8000h
mov sp,bx
mov ss,bx

mov bp,0
jmp _start

 _start:
    call clear

.repeat:        
    mov bp, OS_USERNAME_DESCRIPT
    call print_string
    call Set_BasePointer_std
    call read_string_show
    jmp .repeat

Set_BasePointer_std:
    mov bp,SEAM_STD_BUFFER  
    ret
read_char_show:;() returns al
    call read_char
    cmp al,8
    je .back
    call print
    ret
    .back:
        cmp bp,SEAM_STD_BUFFER
        je .done
        call print
    .done:
    mov al,0
    ret
read_string: ; (ptr bp place to allocate string)
    call read_char
    cmp al,13
    je .done
    call alloc
    inc bp
    cmp bp,SEAM_STD_LIMIT
    jge .resetbp
    jmp read_string
    .done:
        mov al,0
        call alloc
        ret
    .resetbp:
        call Set_BasePointer_std
        jmp read_string
read_string_show: ; (ptr bp place to allocate string)
    call read_char_show
    cmp al,0
    je read_string_show
    cmp al,13
    je .done
    cmp al,8;;NOT GOOD ENOUGH
    je .skip;;NOT GOOD ENOUGH
    call alloc
    inc bp
    .skip:;;NOT GOOD ENOUGH
    cmp bp,SEAM_STD_LIMIT
    jge .resetbp
    jmp read_string_show
    .resetbp:
        call Set_BasePointer_std
        jmp read_string
    .done:
    mov al,0
    call alloc
    call next_line
    ret
read_char: ;() returns al
    mov ax,0x00
    int 0x16
    ret 

clear:; ()
    mov ah,0
    mov al,3
    int 0x10   
    ret
free:;(bp ptr at place start to free, ax at end )
    mov [bp],byte 0
    cmp bp,ax
    je .done
    inc bp
    jmp free
    .done:
    ret
dalloc:; (ptr bp)
    mov al,[bp]
    ret
alloc: ;(bp place to allocate,al byte value)
    mov [bp], al
    ret
clear_line:
    mov dh,0
    call clear
    ret
next_line:
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,0
    inc dh
    cmp dh ,25
    jge clear_line
    int 10h
    ret
previous_line:
    dec dh
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,0
    int 10h
    ret
next_char:; finish
string_compare:;finish  

print: ; (al Character to print, bl color)
    mov ah,0x0E
    int 10h
    ret
print_string: ;(ptr bp Place of string start)
    call dalloc
    cmp al,0
    je .done
    call print
    inc bp
    jmp print_string
    .done:
    ret
OS_WELCOME db 'What is giong on',0
OS_USERNAME_DESCRIPT db 'Username:'
times (510 - ($-$$)) db 0x00
dw 0xAA55
```

Comment: Are you new to 16-bit assembly code development?I ask because there is a lot wrong in this from the way your functions operate, the unusual dalloc routine, and you set up the segment registers improperly at the top of your code

Comment: Yes i am new please tell me how do i set the segment registers

Comment: I would start very simple. Forget about input for a moment. Have you tried to create working code that simply displays strings to the screen?

Comment: yes it worked fine everything prints, except when I add mov bp,8000h mov ss,bp it screws up

Comment: You've marked this emu8086. It looks like nasm. Are you using emu8086?

Comment: no Im using nasm, I just thought its emu because its being run in a virtual machine, im a begginer at this

Comment: Okay, emu8086 is actually a specific program used in academia to teach 16-bit 8086 programming.It doesn't apply here. I've removed the tag and added a couple of new ones.

Comment: oh thanks so what should I do with the segments in the begging how does it work better

Comment: so whats this emu8086 will this app help me with code writing will bios interrupts work there?

Comment: should I use the SS segment and offset with bp or use es ds and offset with di and si?

Comment: The problem with using any memory address relative to [bp] is that it defaults to the SS segment (it is actually the same as [ss:bp]. Part of the problem in your code is that some of it is relative to the stack segment and someof it is relative to the data segment. Would probably be far easier to stop using BP and placing things in the stack area.

Comment: so If I dont use datasegment (ds:di) and dont use ss:bp what should I use to access memory, should i use the extra segment

Comment: But wait how is it relative to the datasegment ive never used the data segment there?

Comment: In 16-bit real mode all memory operands are relative to a segment whether you specify one or not. By default all memory references are implicitly relative to DS (Data Segment). An exception being when BP is used as part of a memory operand. So if you do `mov [si], al` it is the same as `mov [ds:si], al` .If you do `mov [bp], al` it is the same as `mov [ss:bp], al`

Comment: so is it better if I just use the si (datasegment offset)  instead of the bp(stacksegment offset) what difference does it make? I mean whats wrong with using [bp] or using [ss:bp] and how can it hurt?

Comment: I really dont think there is a difference I just changed the bp to SI and ds and the program has the same problem and not a single thing changed infact its the same exact results, still the string only prints if i dont copy anything in ds ( used to be ss and it printed when ss is 0) and its impossible to put in more then 20 bytes it crashes, and when i do add ds to 8000 strings dont print... no change

Comment: In 16 bit real mode the address bus is 20 bit wide, and the physical address is calculated as `segment*16+offset`, the bootloader is for example loaded at physical address `0x07C00` (`0000:7C00` segment:offset). When you are writing bootloader, you are responsible to design memory map layout, where you want to put what (and account for obvious mandatory things like IVT being at 0000:0000 because CPU expects that and you can't move it). Then you can set `cs/ds/es/ss` accordingly and use it. Using `[bp]` or `[ss:bp]` is equal (`[bp]` vs `[ds:bp]` is different), but is `ss:bp` address you want?

Comment: And when you are setting new stack pointer `ss:sp` pair, you must first set `ss` register, and then immediately `sp` (you are doing it in wrong order). The `mov ss,bp` will inhibit interrupts for one instruction, so the next `mov sp,??` will execute right after changing `ss` and no interrupt can happen while the `ss:sp` is only partially updated. Your code does set stack pointer twice (why?) and "partially set stack with interrupts enabled" state happens (as you do not `mov sp,??` right after `mov ss,??`), so you are risking unexpected damage of memory content and malfunction.

Comment: Maybe you should try to produce first some DOS "exe" files to get more used to x86 asm basics and segments and how these things operate, also the DOS exe is often somewhat easier to debug (although if you have already working debugger for bootloader, then this doesn't matter any more .. if you don't have working debugger for bootloader, then that is your most critical problem, stop everything else, and search how to debug your bootloader code, because that's absolutely essential to progress further). Then return back to bootloader writing (if at all .. it's boring and mostly pointless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer complements [the answer given by Sep Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51482748/3628942) that solved the matter of printing (and more).
It deals with the fact that the program keeps crashing after a number of characters have been inputted.

The problem lies in this line:

> ```
> SEAM_STD_BUFFER equ 0
> ```

and its companion:

> ```
> mov bp,SEAM_STD_BUFFER
> ```

Because the stack segment is now correctly positioned at 0, you should no longer store your characters starting at `bp=0`. You do this in the *alloc* code `mov [bp], al`.

You can store it in lots of other places but a good one would be directly behind the bootloader.

```
SEAM_STD_BUFFER equ 0x7E00
```

Comment: It works beautifully thanks, but why wont moving stuff in [0:0] work?

Comment: @Dodo On x86 the interrupt vector table occupies the 1024 lowest addresses in memory from 0000h:0000h -> 0000h:0400h. If you write random stuff in this area then the interrupt vectors get corrupted and soon the computer will hang!

Answer (score 2):

## Getting your printing on track

> ```
> xor ax,ax
> mov bx,ax
> mov bx,cx    <-- Here CX goes to BX
> mov dx,0
> mov ds,bx    <-- Here (via BX) CX goes to DS
> mov es,bx    <-- Here (via BX) CX goes to ES
> ```

You don't setup the `DS` and `ES` segment registers correctly!
You've stored the value of `CX` in them **but `CX` never got initialized with any useful value**.

---

> ```
> mov bp,0
> mov sp,bp
> mov ss,bp
> mov bx,8000h
> mov sp,bx
> mov ss,bx
> ```

There's alot wrong with how you setup the stack. Doing it twice can't help much! Also when setting up the stackpointer always first assign `SS` and immediately after assign `SP`. The order is important.

For the actual value to put in `SS`, frankly you got no choice. (Technically you have but let's not complicate things...) Given that you want to use `BP` to point at your strings and that the whole program gets encoded with an `ORG 0x7C00` the only correct value to put in `SS` is zero.
I suggest you write:

```
xor ax, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0x7C00
```

This will put the stack just below your bootloader program, a safe place.
And because `DS` and `ES` also need a good initialization, make the whole thing:

```
xor ax, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0x7C00
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
```

---

> ```
> print: ; (al Character to print, bl color)
>     mov ah,0x0E
>     int 10h
>     ret
> ```

This *print* routine still needs that you say to which display page the BIOS teletype function should write. The selection is done via the `BH` register.

```
print:
    mov bh, 0
    mov ah, 0x0E
    int 10h
    ret
```

In order to verify that the printing works, you could make the program wait for a key:

```
_start:
    call clear
.repeat:        
    mov  bp, OS_USERNAME_DESCRIPT
    call print_string
    mov  ah, 00h     ;Wait for a key
    int  16h         ;Wait for a key
```

Once you're confident that this part of the code works fine, you just remove these 2 lines.

---

## Something that will backfire eventually

> ```
> OS_USERNAME_DESCRIPT db 'Username:'
> times (510 - ($-$$)) db 0x00
> ```

Do terminate the string with an explicit zero. Don't rely on the following padding that happens to use zeroes.

In future:

- you might pad with some other value than zero
- the bootloader might got crowded so there would be no padding at all

Comment: Thanks for the answer :), The code would still freeze after typing so much characters, I did change the initialization, and added the terminator to the string and specified the page number in the print label